# Trigger store information duplicate

Tags: sql-server

I am using Trigger & this trigger is fire on the  table when i am fill the information by UI Form. First time it is inserting the record proper in the table.

Again update it the information then it is store two records in the tables. 
Mean Two Rows are inserted in the table against update. What I am doing wrong in Trigger.

My Trigger is given below:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trPkgDPRBidSubmissionDetails] 
   ON  [dbo].[tblPkgDPRBidSubmissionDetails] 
   AFTER insert, update, delete
AS 

BEGIN

 DECLARE @Action as varchar(50);
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;


SET @Action = 'Insert'; -- Set Action to Insert by default.
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
BEGIN
    SET @Action = 
        CASE
           WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) THEN 'UPDATE' 
           ELSE 'DELETE' 
        END
END


if( @Action = 'DELETE')
begin 
    insert into tblPkgDPRBidSubmissionDetailsAT(iUserId,cAction, dtAction,iActionOwner,iPackage,dtInitialDesignReport,dtDPR, dtBidDocuments,dtExternalReview1,dtComplianceToPWD1,dtComplianceToExtAgency1,dtExternalReview2,dtComplianceToPWD2,dtComplianceToExtAgency2, dtApprovalFromExternalAgency,dtIFB,dtUpToIssue,dtPreMeeting,dtBidOpeningMeetingOriginal, dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension1,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension2,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension3, iNumberOfBidsSold,iNumberOfBidsReceived)

select iUserId,@Action, getdate(), 1,iPackage,dtInitialDesignReport, dtDPR, dtBidDocuments,dtExternalReview1, dtComplianceToPWD1,dtComplianceToExtAgency1,dtExternalReview2,dtComplianceToPWD2,dtComplianceToExtAgency2,dtApprovalFromExternalAgency, dtIFB,dtUpToIssue,dtPreMeeting,dtBidOpeningMeetingOriginal,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension1,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension2,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension3, iNumberOfBidsSold,iNumberOfBidsReceived
from deleted;
end

else 
begin

insert into tblPkgDPRBidSubmissionDetailsAT(iUserId,cAction, dtAction,iActionOwner,iPackage,dtInitialDesignReport,dtDPR, dtBidDocuments,dtExternalReview1,dtComplianceToPWD1,dtComplianceToExtAgency1,dtExternalReview2,dtComplianceToPWD2,dtComplianceToExtAgency2, dtApprovalFromExternalAgency,dtIFB,dtUpToIssue,dtPreMeeting,dtBidOpeningMeetingOriginal, dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension1,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension2, dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension3,iNumberOfBidsSold,iNumberOfBidsReceived)

select iUserId,@Action, getdate(), 1,iPackage,dtInitialDesignReport, dtDPR, dtBidDocuments,dtExternalReview1, dtComplianceToPWD1,dtComplianceToExtAgency1,dtExternalReview2,dtComplianceToPWD2,dtComplianceToExtAgency2,dtApprovalFromExternalAgency, dtIFB,dtUpToIssue,dtPreMeeting,dtBidOpeningMeetingOriginal,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension1,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension2,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension3, iNumberOfBidsSold,iNumberOfBidsReceived
from inserted;
end
-- Insert statements for trigger here
-- action owner field to be udpated

END
```

Answer (score 0):

The code inside your ELSE block handles both INSERT and UPDATE actions, so you end up with another row inserted into tblPkgDPRBidSubmissionDetailsAT table in both cases.

I think this is what you need:

```
if( @Action = 'DELETE')
begin 
    insert into tblPkgDPRBidSubmissionDetailsAT(iUserId,cAction, dtAction,iActionOwner,iPackage,dtInitialDesignReport,dtDPR, dtBidDocuments,dtExternalReview1,dtComplianceToPWD1,dtComplianceToExtAgency1,dtExternalReview2,dtComplianceToPWD2,dtComplianceToExtAgency2, dtApprovalFromExternalAgency,dtIFB,dtUpToIssue,dtPreMeeting,dtBidOpeningMeetingOriginal, dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension1,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension2,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension3, iNumberOfBidsSold,iNumberOfBidsReceived)    
    select iUserId,@Action, getdate(), 1,iPackage,dtInitialDesignReport, dtDPR, dtBidDocuments,dtExternalReview1, dtComplianceToPWD1,dtComplianceToExtAgency1,dtExternalReview2,dtComplianceToPWD2,dtComplianceToExtAgency2,dtApprovalFromExternalAgency, dtIFB,dtUpToIssue,dtPreMeeting,dtBidOpeningMeetingOriginal,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension1,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension2,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension3, iNumberOfBidsSold,iNumberOfBidsReceived
    from deleted;
end

else 
begin
    if @Action = 'INSERT'
        insert into tblPkgDPRBidSubmissionDetailsAT(iUserId,cAction, dtAction,iActionOwner,iPackage,dtInitialDesignReport,dtDPR, dtBidDocuments,dtExternalReview1,dtComplianceToPWD1,dtComplianceToExtAgency1,dtExternalReview2,dtComplianceToPWD2,dtComplianceToExtAgency2, dtApprovalFromExternalAgency,dtIFB,dtUpToIssue,dtPreMeeting,dtBidOpeningMeetingOriginal, dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension1,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension2, dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension3,iNumberOfBidsSold,iNumberOfBidsReceived)    
        select iUserId,@Action, getdate(), 1,iPackage,dtInitialDesignReport, dtDPR, dtBidDocuments,dtExternalReview1, dtComplianceToPWD1,dtComplianceToExtAgency1,dtExternalReview2,dtComplianceToPWD2,dtComplianceToExtAgency2,dtApprovalFromExternalAgency, dtIFB,dtUpToIssue,dtPreMeeting,dtBidOpeningMeetingOriginal,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension1,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension2,dtBidOpeningMeetingExtension3, iNumberOfBidsSold,iNumberOfBidsReceived
        from inserted;
end
```